# How to to do database migrations in .NET SOA architecture correctly

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, database-migration, soa

We have distributed SOA architecture with a lot of services. Most services have their own data model but may also require configuration data changes on other "shared" services. This configuration data depends on which shared service is needed but is mostly customer related data like customer data, order types, parameters that affect the process flow, ...

I have looked at database migration tool and came up with FluentMigrator.
https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator

When using a database migration tool, how do you handle migrations in different services. In my opinion each service should be responsible for handling its own data model but should not be responsible for updating another service data model.

Check the following scenario.

[image]

When deploying service A we need to do:

1. Update Service A data model + static data
2. Create customer, customer type, available services, parameters ... in CRM service
3. Upload a customer workflow
4. Add channel, subscriptions and other message related configuration to EAI system
5. Create service account, grant permissions, update service catalog in Portal service ESB

Currently it is al done by hand. But we need to set up continuous delivery which requires us to automate these configurations.

The schemas are updated automatically as part of the deployment process of the services. But what to do with the configuration data? Where should I store those?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but It sounds like the question is not really about database migrations, more about synchronizing configuration data across many different services.

Comment: Exactly, but the configuration is currently mostly database configuration.